# How to use different implementaions of an interface in C?

Tags: c, interface, implementation

I want to implement a differentiable function in C. Essentially, it is a struct that has two funcion pointers. One to calculate a function value, another to calculate its differential. The struct is declared inside of a header file. Ideally, my application should only know about this interface: the object is a struct with two function pointers, those functions convert a `double` to another `double`.

The problem is that I don't know how to properly provide an implementation (or multiple implementations) of this interface to my program. I have five differentiable functions and I need to switch between them in runtime. I also can decide to use more or less of them in future. In Java I would just `import` the interface and its implementations (may be the entire package), it would ensure type safety and unused imports would not impact performance. But in C I can't just include whatever I want because it gets literally copied into the program. I also don't want to change compilation commands inside of my Makefile since it is not explicitly reflected in my code.

Memory usage and performance aren't that important as readability and modularity. I do not insist on that my approach is fundamentally right and I'm willing to switch it. Is there a conventional way of solving such a task in C?

Comment: Have you considered using an abstract base class as the declared type, and use derived implementing classes as the actual type?

Comment: @AcId I know that generally this is what I should do, but I don't know how to do this in C with structs

Comment: If I've understood correctly, you can just define all your functions as normal double fn1(double x); double dfn1(double x) etc. then set the function pointers to the appropriate function at runtime mystruct.fn_ptr = &fn1; mystruct.dfn_ptr = &dfn1 etc. or is this not what you meant?

Comment: You can compile each implementation as a *dynamically loadable library* (or *shared object* if you come from the Unix-speaking world) and load one that you choose at run time by name. This way you can just drop in a new implementation without ever changing your main program or build script.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set up your build script such that it picks up an entire directory full of source files. This way, in order to add a new implementation, you add another source file to a directory, modify your main program such that it knows about the new implementation, and recompile.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit does it mean that compiler will take all the `.o` files from the directory? Even unused ones?

Comment: Normally the compiler compiles the files one by one and yes the build system will cause all of them to be compiled, because the build system doesn't have enough information to find out which files are actually used. It is possible to arrange for the linker to eliminate the unused ones when producing the final executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Essentially, it is a struct that has two funcion pointers. One to calculate a function value, another to calculate its differential.

```
struct Function { double (*f)(double), (*df)(double); };
```

> The problem is that I don't know how to properly provide an implementation (or multiple implementations) of this interface to my program.

```
struct Function Sine = { sin, cos };
```

Demonstration:

```
struct Function { double (*f)(double), (*df)(double); };


#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct Function Sine = { sin, cos };


static void Demonstrate(struct Function F, double x)
{
    printf("f(%g) = %g.\n", x, F.f(x));
    printf("df(%g) = %g.\n", x, F.df(x));
}


int main(void)
{
    Demonstrate(Sine, 3.1415926535897932384626433/6);
}
```

Comment: So if I want to use an implementation of `Function` (which is `Sine`) in another compilation unit, then I need to declare my struct as `extern` and link and object file to my main program?

Comment: @SunofAbeach: You could declare `struct Function` objects with `extern` or you could pass them by pointers. For example, `main` could call a function `GetFunction` that took a number and return a function you identified by that number, as in `struct Function *Pointer = GetFunction(17);`. `GetFunction` would be in another source file and would return the address of a `struct Function` defined in that file.